# Error while accessing application with ProxyPass

Tags: apache, jboss, jboss7.x, virtualhost

I have hosted a JBoss application in a server.
I can access the application with IP address mentioned in the URL:

e.g.`x.x.x.x:8080/dashboard/admindashboard`

But when I am trying to access the application using a domain say www.admin.domainname.com, I am facing following error in the browser:

> The requested URL /dashboard/admindashboard was not found on this
>   server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Please find the `virtualhost` content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.admin.domainname.com
  ServerAlias admin.domainname.com
  ProxyPass /errors !
  ProxyPass / http://x.x.x.x:8080/dashboard/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://x.x.x.x:8080/dashboard/
  ProxyErrorOverride On
  ErrorDocument 404 /errors/error.html
</VirtualHost>
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines on how to write questions. For starters: 1. Please format your code. 2. Add more code to your question to help us understand it better and for future readers to benefit from this question. 3. Look for other questions which might help you out already. 4. Format your text, and give us a minimum working example

Comment: Thanks will do so.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that you can access to the `schema://x.x.x.x:8080/dashboard/admindashboard` directly on your JBoss, the problem is that your proxy pass directives aren't setting the right app's context.

Set something like this,

```
ProxyPass /dashboard http://x.x.x.x:8080/dashboard
ProxyPassReverse /dashboard http://x.x.x.x:8080/dashboard
```

Note: I assume you aren't trying to make a load balancer. That is a different story.